# Finding game launcher executables in directory C#

Tags: c#, exe, executable, steam

I'm trying to find executable files for games; however some are nested (For example Ark: Survival Evolved) (*A:\Steam Games\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\ShooterGame.exe*)

I've spent ages trying to find a way to only find the executables which are relevant.

[This link](https://pastebin.com/ZGFGQuq1) shows games when we don't search recursively. It finds most, but not all .exe's

[This link](https://pastebin.com/4kHXFi80) shows games searching recursively, but also shows a bunch of binaries/redist exes.

Initially I tried excluding "bin","binary","binaries","redist" folders but that then didn't give me Ark: Survival Evolved for example.

I also considered filtering the .exe's based on their size, but Aperture Tag has a *QC_Eyes.exe* at 3055KB, but Tomb Raider II.exe is 892KB.

Here's the method I'm using to find the steam installation directory, and check the libraryfolders.vdf file for where the library locations are. For now I'm just writing to console so that I can see what the outputs are.

If anyone has any tips on how I can find the right files for the right games it would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
        public void SearchSteam()
    {
        steamGameDirs.Clear();
        string steam32 = "SOFTWARE\\VALVE\\";
        string steam64 = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Valve\\";
        string steam32path;
        string steam64path;
        string config32path;
        string config64path;
        RegistryKey key32 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(steam32);
        RegistryKey key64 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(steam64);

        foreach(string k32subKey in key32.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subKey = key32.OpenSubKey(k32subKey))
            {
                steam32path = subKey.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
                config32path = steam32path + "/steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf";
                if (File.Exists(config32path))
                {
                    string[] configLines = File.ReadAllLines(config32path);
                    foreach(var item in configLines)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("32:  " + item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(string k64subKey in key64.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subKey = key64.OpenSubKey(k64subKey))
            {
                steam64path = subKey.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
                config64path = steam64path + "/steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf";
                string driveRegex = @"[A-Z]:\\";
                if (File.Exists(config64path))
                {
                    string[] configLines = File.ReadAllLines(config64path);
                    foreach (var item in configLines)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("64:  " + item);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(item, driveRegex);
                        if(item != string.Empty && match.Success)
                        {
                            string matched = match.ToString();
                            string item2 = item.Substring(item.IndexOf(matched));
                            item2 = item2.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
                            steamGameDirs.Add(item2);
                        }
                    }
                    steamGameDirs.Add(steam64path + "\\steamapps\\common\\");
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(string item in steamGameDirs)
        {
            string GameTitle;
            string[] Executables = new string[0];
            string[] steamGames = Directory.GetDirectories(item);
            foreach (var dir in steamGames)
            {
                string title = dir.Substring(dir.IndexOf("\\common\\"));
                string[] titlex = title.Split('\\');
                title = titlex[2].ToString();
                GameTitle = title;
                Console.WriteLine("Title: " + GameTitle);
                Console.WriteLine("Directory: " + dir);
                string[] executables = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                int num = 0;
                foreach (var ex in executables)
                {
                    //add "ex" to Executables[] if poss
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    num++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no standardized way to determine which executables are the "correct" ones. Sometimes they contain the entire game in their binary, sometimes they are just a very thin wrapper. The usual solution to this is to have a database which contains the name of the exe. You could try to get this data from an existing source (profiles of graphic card drivers come to my mind), but otherwise you've got little choice but to maintain your own mappings.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. You can move your steam folder. You can install off a disk to somewhere else entirely. How would you know which exe are games? For example. My copy of winspww2 is in E:\WinspWW2

Comment: It's stored in appcache\appinfo.vdf: each game has an entry there and an an 'executable' property. However it's stored in a binary format that you'll need to unpick. There's some code out there already, e.g. [the Python steamfiles module](https://pypi.org/project/steamfiles/)

Comment: Thank you @Rup, I'll have to look into that. 
Andy the steam folders are stored in the library.vdf so we can find where the games are stored, just not the .exe file for the game (which Rup has helped with). 
Lennart yeah I thought so, I'll also have a look at that, most likely have a fallback to the user selecting the right one.
Liam well, it's a file that launches the game.. so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to do what I can, so first I detect where steam is installed through the registry, then I check /steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf for where the users libraries are, then check those libraries for any "top level" executables. The program then lets the user select their own exe if one isn't found in the top directory.

Seems like the best solution for now as the steamfiles module isn't currently active.

```
public void SearchSteam()
{
    steamGameDirs.Clear();
    string steam32 = "SOFTWARE\\VALVE\\";
    string steam64 = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Valve\\";
    string steam32path;
    string steam64path;
    string config32path;
    string config64path;
    RegistryKey key32 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(steam32);
    RegistryKey key64 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(steam64);
    if (key64.ToString() == null || key64.ToString() == "")
    {
        foreach (string k32subKey in key32.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subKey = key32.OpenSubKey(k32subKey))
            {
                steam32path = subKey.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
                config32path = steam32path + "/steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf";
                string driveRegex = @"[A-Z]:\\";
                if (File.Exists(config32path))
                {
                    string[] configLines = File.ReadAllLines(config32path);
                    foreach (var item in configLines)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("32:  " + item);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(item, driveRegex);
                        if (item != string.Empty && match.Success)
                        {
                            string matched = match.ToString();
                            string item2 = item.Substring(item.IndexOf(matched));
                            item2 = item2.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
                            item2 = item2.Replace("\"", "\\steamapps\\common\\");
                            steamGameDirs.Add(item2);
                        }
                    }
                    steamGameDirs.Add(steam32path + "\\steamapps\\common\\");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach(string k64subKey in key64.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (RegistryKey subKey = key64.OpenSubKey(k64subKey))
        {
            steam64path = subKey.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
            config64path = steam64path + "/steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf";
            string driveRegex = @"[A-Z]:\\";
            if (File.Exists(config64path))
            {
                string[] configLines = File.ReadAllLines(config64path);
                foreach (var item in configLines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("64:  " + item);
                    Match match = Regex.Match(item, driveRegex);
                    if(item != string.Empty && match.Success)
                    {
                        string matched = match.ToString();
                        string item2 = item.Substring(item.IndexOf(matched));
                        item2 = item2.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
                        item2 = item2.Replace("\"", "\\steamapps\\common\\");
                        steamGameDirs.Add(item2);
                    }
                }
                steamGameDirs.Add(steam64path + "\\steamapps\\common\\");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attached the code so others can see how I've done it. I know it's not the best but it's working

Comment: Looking into the same. Seems the next clue lies in the steamapps\appmanifest_appid.acf, which again has pointers that leads to \depotcache\appiddepotid_manifestid.manifest which contains some metadata in some binary form.

Answer (score 1):

The keydata seems to be in the appinfo.vdf file. So a somewhat working code to get the correct EXE file for steam games is as follows. Where the game is an EA game with a pointer to an URL or there is no data in the appinfo.vdf a fallback to your previous solution could be used. If anyone got a good parser of the appinfo.vdf the code would be better and not as hacky as the "IndexOf" solution.

GetSteamPath() in the below code can be updated to fetch from registry.

I am going to use that code to fix those petchy steam links that goes back to that anonymous globe-url icon.

(Written in .Net 5.0 - seems IndexOf for .4.7.2 is quirky. doesnt like \x00 I think)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SteamAppsParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var libs = GetSteamLibs();
            var apps = GetSteamApps(libs);
        }

        static List<AppInfo> GetSteamApps(List<string> steamLibs)
        {
            var apps = new List<AppInfo>();
            foreach (var lib in steamLibs)
            {
                var appMetaDataPath = Path.Combine(lib, "SteamApps");
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(appMetaDataPath, "*.acf");
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var appInfo = GetAppInfo(file);
                    if (appInfo != null)
                    {
                        apps.Add(appInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            return apps;
        }

        static AppInfo GetAppInfo(string appMetaFile)
        {
            var fileDataLines = File.ReadAllLines(appMetaFile);

            var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            foreach (var line in fileDataLines)
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(line, @"\s*""(?<key>\w+)""\s+""(?<val>.*)""");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
                    var val = match.Groups["val"].Value;
                    dic[key] = val;
                }
            }

            AppInfo appInfo = null;

            if (dic.Keys.Count > 0)
            {
                appInfo = new AppInfo();
                var appId = dic["appid"];
                var name = dic["name"];
                var installDir = dic["installDir"];

                var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(appMetaFile);
                var libGameRoot = Path.Combine(path, "common", installDir);

                if (!Directory.Exists(libGameRoot)) return null;

                appInfo.Id = appId;
                appInfo.Name = name;
                appInfo.Manifest = appMetaFile;
                appInfo.GameRoot = libGameRoot;
                appInfo.InstallDir = installDir;
                appInfo.SteamUrl = $"steam://runsteamid/{appId}";
                //if (appInfo.Name.StartsWith("Sid Meier"))
                appInfo.Executable = GetExecutable(appInfo);
            }

            return appInfo;
        }


        static string _appInfoText = null;
        static string GetExecutable(AppInfo appInfo)
        {
            if (_appInfoText == null)
            {
                var appInfoFile = Path.Combine(GetSteamPath(), "appcache", "appinfo.vdf");
                var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(appInfoFile);
                _appInfoText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            }
            var startIndex = 0;
            int maxTries = 50;
            var fullName = "";

            do
            {
                var startOfDataArea = _appInfoText.IndexOf($"\x00\x01name\x00{appInfo.Name}\x00", startIndex);
                if (startOfDataArea < 0 && maxTries == 50) startOfDataArea = _appInfoText.IndexOf($"\x00\x01gamedir\x00{appInfo.Name}\x00", startIndex); //Alternative1
                if (startOfDataArea < 0 && maxTries == 50) startOfDataArea = _appInfoText.IndexOf($"\x00\x01name\x00{appInfo.Name}\x00", startIndex); //Alternative2
                if (startOfDataArea > 0)
                {
                    startIndex = startOfDataArea + 10;
                    int nextLaunch = -1;
                    do
                    {
                        var executable = _appInfoText.IndexOf($"\x00\x01executable\x00", startOfDataArea);
                        if (executable>-1 && nextLaunch == -1)
                        {
                            nextLaunch = _appInfoText.IndexOf($"\x00\x01launch\x00", executable);
                        }

                        if ((nextLaunch <= 0 || executable < nextLaunch) && executable > 0)
                        {
                            if (executable > 0)
                            {
                                executable += 10;
                                string filename = "";
                                while (_appInfoText[executable] != '\x00')
                                {
                                    filename += _appInfoText[executable];
                                    executable++;
                                }
                                if (filename.Contains("://"))
                                {
                                    //EA or other external
                                    return filename; //Need to use other means to grab the EXE here.
                                }

                                fullName = Path.Combine(appInfo.GameRoot, filename);

                                startOfDataArea = executable + 1;
                                startIndex = startOfDataArea + 10;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    while (!File.Exists(fullName) && maxTries-- > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            } while (!File.Exists(fullName) && maxTries-- > 0);

            if (File.Exists(fullName)) return fullName;

            return null;
        }



        static List<string> GetSteamLibs()
        {

            var steamPath = GetSteamPath();
            var libraries = new List<string>() { steamPath };

            var listFile = Path.Combine(steamPath, @"steamapps\libraryfolders.vdf");
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(listFile);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var match = Regex.Match(line, @"""(?<path>\w:\\\\.*)""");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var path = match.Groups["path"].Value.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        libraries.Add(path);
                    }
                }
            }
            return libraries;
        }

        static string GetSteamPath()
        {
            return @"C:\Spill\Steam";
        }

        class AppInfo
        {
            public string Id { get; internal set; }
            public string Name { get; internal set; }
            public string SteamUrl { get; internal set; }
            public string Manifest { get; internal set; }
            public string GameRoot { get; internal set; }
            public string Executable { get; internal set; }
            public string InstallDir { get; internal set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Name} ({Id}) - {SteamUrl} - {Executable}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```